# Assetic dump reveals "_settings.scss failed to import not found or unreadable"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, zurb-foundation, assetic, symfony-2.4

I have been learning how to use assetic filters and integrating compass/foundation5 through assetics. When I attempt to use assetic:dump I get a mess of errors and despite my best efforts I have yet to find the solution. First off I think the root of the error lies here.

```
Output:
  error assetic_compassyGuG5K.scss (Line 13 of src/test/CoreBundle/Resources/public/scss/_settings.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions.
  Load paths:
    /tmp
    /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/compass-0.12.6/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
    /home/test/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/compass-0.12.6/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
    /var/www/test.local/public_html/src/test/CoreBundle/Resources/public/scss
```

I have attempted to do anything I can think of to clear the error (aside removing the filter completely, which would fix it). I even attempted to use foundation to load the site and though I got rid of this error it was replaced by a error stating that the foundation.xml could not be located.

My question is do I need to add the config.rb to the filter to define the locations or am I missing something all together in the filter?

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: true
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        compass:
            bin: /home/nathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/compass
            apply_to: "/.scss$"
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

parameters:
    assetic.ruby.bin: /home/nathan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Well I solved the issue of missing file, but I am still receiving a couple of error that involves the assetic vendor.

`PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '.' in /var/www/sirius.local/public_html/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Factory/Worker/EnsureFilterWorker.php on line 53`
and
`PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '.' in /var/www/sirius.local/public_html/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Factory/Worker/EnsureFilterWorker.php on line 55`

Comment: issue was self solved. I needed to first add the foundation bin to the filter and as for the multiple php warnings, that was due to this line `#    apply_to: "/.scss$"` which I commented out.

Answer (score 0):

The `apply_to` checks a regular expression, and `\` indicates that the next character will be escaped (dot in this case), then, `/` should be replaced with `\`.